# Dynamically Column Creation as per Branch Data

Tags: sql

I need to get result from Existing Table and my current result is like

```
Code    Name            Branch  Dr          Cr          Net                 
1001    Closing Stock   UP      150000      195000      -45000                  
1001    Closing Stock   DL      159.74      0           159.74                  
1001    Closing Stock   CH      0           24.37       -24.37                  
1002    IGST Payable    UP      0           135.37      -135.37                 
1002    IGST Payable    DL      0           200         -200                    
1002    IGST Payable    CH      200         0           200                 
1003    Sundry Debtors  UP      15767000    0           15767000                    
1003    Sundry Debtors  DL      0           181716      -181716
```

Note :

- If Branches Increase then Branch wise (Debit,Credit,Net) Fields should be Create automatically.

And Result should be like this

```
Code   Name UPDr    UPCr    UPNet   CHDr  CHCr  CHNet  DLDr   DLCr  DLNet
1001   Stk  1500    1950    -450    0     24.37 -24.37 159    0     159.74
1002   IGST 0       135.37  -135    200   0     200    0      181   -181
1003   Sund 157     0       157     159   0     159    200    0     200
```

Please help for the same.

Comment: What is the SQL statement you tried ("my current result"), what is your issue in achieving the expected result?

Comment: learn what is [pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server) and how to implement it, also you didn't specify your SQL dialect

Comment: You have some problem with dimensions - why does 150000 turns into 1500 and at the same time 159.74 turns into 159 after aggregation?

The solution might be to use LEFT JOIN with some IFNULL-like predicate, but you really do need to specify what exact tool/SQL dialect you are working with.